# Facebook "Like" button is posting old information

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The Facebook "Like" button is posting old information for my website; opticaljump.com. It shows up on Facebook as "Sarasota Graphic Design" when it should say, "International Graphic Design". I have changed the meta tags on my page and ran it through the Facebook debugger as recommended elsewhere on this site, but it still shows up wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's because facebook has cached old meta data, you need to lint your page so it updates their cached data. Here's a similar question asked before and the answer is posted there: [Refresh meta data in posted URL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6754078/refresh-meta-data-in-posted-url/6754506#6754506)